# Key detect raspberry pi4

Tags: python, raspberry-pi4, remote-control

I am trying to do a project that prints something on an LCD and if I press a key on the remote control will stop printing that text and print something else. I am searching for something similar with the 'keyboard' package but I need it to work with external devices like IR remote or something similar not only with the keyboard.

Eg.:
LCD prints:
Hello StackOverflow!

and after 5 seconds
LCD print:
HI!

If I press any key on the remote:
LCD prints:
Hello StackOverflow!

key detected
LCD prints:
See you soon!
without the last part.

I want to find a module/package or a command that can help me do this.

Comment: First decide which device you want to use as input (like a IR remote). This device will have a manual or a tutorial on how to read it in the raspberry. Here you have an example of using IR remote in a raspberry  https://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote

Comment: I already have lirc package and the IR remote is working But I can't find a command that will stop my code only if I press a key.
The issue is that whenever I need to read a key it will stop my code until I read it and than it will continue it's executions. 
My main goal is to do something like :
While True:
    If button_pressed:
        Do something
        break
    else:
        Do anything else

Comment: please post the code you have then. If you need help with your code then you must post your code in order for us to help

Comment: from remoteControl import init_irw, next_key
from displayLCD import init_lcd
import sys
import time
from Python_Course.Week10.FinalProject.Games.Guess.GuessFinal2 import game_start_guess
from HWbasic import print_navigations

lcd = init_lcd()
lcd.clear()
init_irw()

def main():
    while True:
        lcd.write_string("Humidity: and temp:")
              if key_pressed():
                    while True:
                          # start_game return -1 if hit back
                          if start_games(lcd) == -1:
                               break

Comment: of course the code must be in the question, properly formatted, not as an unformatted comment.

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional button and checked for it if it's state is high or low.
Checking the button from the ir will just stop the whole program until a button is pressed

Answer (score -1):

Just create a state machine and use it to decide whether running the code or not.

I implemented the code in C for an Arduino, but you can get the same in python for a raspberry pi. The concept of a state machine is the same.

```cpp
enum State{
  RUNNING,
  STOPPED,
};

enum State currentState = RUNNING;

void setup() {
  // configure your IR device
}

void onButton1Pressed() {
  // call this function when button 1 from IR is pressed.
  // This function changes the state to RUNNING

  currentState = RUNNING;
}

void onButton2Pressed() {
  // call this function when button 2 from IR is pressed.
  // This function changes the state to STOPPED

  currentState = STOPPED;
}

void program_state_stopped() {
    // this function executes when the state is STOPPED
    // in the example, it prints I'm waiting every second
    print("I'm waiting...");
    delay(1000);
}

void program_state_running() {
    // this function executes when the state is RUNNING
    // in the example, it prints I'm running every second
    print("I'm running...");
    delay(1000);
}

void loop() {
  // Here you need to read the IR buttons and call the onButtonPressed functions if  button is pressed
  // Or even better use interruptions to read buttons and change states

  // once the button has been processed, check the current state and call the appropiate function
  if (currentState == STOPPED) {
    // state is STOPPED so we call its corresponding function
    program_state_stopped();
  }
  else if (currentState == RUNNING) {
    // state is RUNNINGso we call its corresponding function
    program_state_running();
  }
}
```

Comment: I see your point but It doesn't fully solve my issue. The problem is that when I read the button(When I call the function to verify what button do I hit) Everything stops until I hit a button but I want my code to keep printing thing until I press something. Is more like:
while(True){
 print("hello")
if (a button is pressed){
print("Goodbye")
break
}
}

And the output will be something like
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
.
.
.
Hello
Goodbye

But now is something like 
Hello
And it waits for me to press any keys

Comment: when the state is STOPPED, instead  of not executing anythng you can call your own function and print whatever your want. Same for the running state or any other state you create. With a state machine like the one in the code you can do what your want and more. I edited the code, so each state has it's own function where you can put the code you want. This is a very basic template of a state machine, you can use it to build your functionalities on top of that.